# Can I organize my message properties when using Thymeleaf in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing a Thymeleaf form that needs human-readable labels for rows that are identified by namespaced keys, where `flow.key` is something like `com.example.Flow`:

```
<td class="flow-name" th:text="#{|flow:${flow.key}|}" />
```

I am successfully reading these out of `messages.properties`, but aggregating all pages' text into one large properties file is big and cluttered. Out of the box, [Thymeleaf would look for message bundles alongside the template files](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-message-resolver), but the Spring integration appears to entirely replace the internal resolver with the Spring `MessageSource`, which doesn't seem to be able to use the page-specific context.

Is there a clean way to configure Thymeleaf 3 in Spring Boot 2.5 to re-enable the default behavior of scoped message resolution?